# how to remove elevation/shadow from container

Tags: flutter, dart, containers

```
      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 235, 235, 235),
      child: secondHalf.length == '' ? Text(widget.text) : Text(firstHalf),
    );
```

[image: Picture of how it looks, i dont want those things at the side]

Picture of how it looks, i dont want those things at the side

Comment: you sure that's a `Container`? By default, Container doesn't have elevation.

Comment: I forgot to say that the container is ontop of a scaffold